# How do I send an E-mail from a webpage?

Tags: html, email

I've been trying to learn the basics of HTML, and in doing this I've been designing my own rudimentary webpage. I don't plan on making it public at all, but it's good to help me to learn all of the different aspects of both HTML and CSS. In doing this, I've added a Contact section on one of the pages, that includes both an email address and a form that allows for an E-mail to be sent, I used one of the tutorials on W3Schools to create it. For the purposes of this I have removed my own email address, and replaced it with `someone@example.com`, but here is the output of this specific part of the code:

[image: E-mail]

However, whenever I try to fill the form in to test it, I get this pop-up message. If I click cancel, then nothing happens, but if I click OK then then the mail app on my computer is opened. But the message that I typed into the form isn't there, and the E-mail address that I type into the box to send from is just changed to the default address on my computer.

[image: Pop-up]

So what can I do to prevent this pop-up message, and to just send the e-mail to me?

Here is the relevant code from the HTML document:

```
<h2 style = 'font-weight:normal'><a name = 'Contact' id = 'Contact'></a>Contact me:</h2>

<p>
  You can reach me at: someone@example.com <br />
  Or by just using the form below
</p>

<form action = 'mailto: someone@example.com' method = 'post' enctype = 'text/plain'>
  <input type = 'text' name = 'name' placeholder = 'Name'> <br />
  <br />
  <input type = 'text' name = 'mail' placeholder = 'E-mail'> <br />
  <br />
  <input type = 'text' name = 'comment' size = '50' placeholder = 'Comment'> <br />
  <br />
  <input type = 'submit' value = 'Send'>
  <input type = 'reset' value = 'Reset'>
</form>
```

If HTML isn't going to be enough to send an e-mail from a webpage, and I need another language to write a program that can do it, I am quite competent in Python, and I know C# to some extent. However, I've never used JavaScript, PHP, Perl, or anything else (I don't know what sort of languages would be appropriate)

Comment: You can't get rid of it. You are opening up the mail client of the user's computer.

Comment: @epascarello so is there no better way for me to do this, or am I just going to have to forget about it?

Comment: You are going to get this pop up unless you use a server side script like PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Using the user's email client, that is what is going to happen.

Comment: @epascarello bacially any way that works, if it's too complicated though I might just remove it from the page

Comment: It works, it is just a warning to the user.

Comment: @epascarello I doesn't seem to, as when it opens the mail client, the form information is not preserved

Comment: because mailTo does not use form data, you need to provide it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#E-mail_links

Comment: @epascarello — You are confusing mailto links and mailto form actions. They work differently.

Comment: `mailto:` as a form action is [notoriously unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). Use an HTTP(S) action and server side form mailer.

Comment: @Quentin So if this is so unreliable, is there a better way of approaching the problem?

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox — As I (and the link in my last comment) said: "Use an HTTP(S) action and server side form mailer"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit the form to go to an email it's simple really. You could use a simple server-side language like PHP. You'll need 3 files. One file that houses the front-end form contents, one file that processes the form once the user hits the submit button and a thank you page after the form gets sent to let the user know that the form has been submitted. Here is a demo below.

**HTML:**

```
 <form action="processor.php" method="post" id="myForm">
        <label for="firstname"></label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname" required>
        <label for="lastname"></label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname" required> 
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
        <label for="comments"></label>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="32" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Questions & Comments"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

**PHP (processor.php file)**

```
/***********************************************************/
/*******   Set the receipient email address below   ********/
/*******   And set the subject line of the email    ********/
/*$recipient_email = "testemail@yahoo.com";*/
$recipient_email = "testemail@yahoo.com";
$email_subject_line = "Mail from Website";

/***********************************************************/
/***********************************************************/

if(isset($_POST['firstname']))
{
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

   if(!empty($firstName) && 
    !empty($lastName) &&
    !empty($email) &&
    !empty($comments))
   {

$message = "Name: $firstName, Lastname: $lastName, Phone: $phoneNumber, 
Email: $email, Comments: $comments";

send_mail($email, $message, $recipient_email, $email_subject_line);

   }
}

function send_mail($email, $message, $recipient_email, $email_subject_line)
{
$to = $recipient_email;
$from = $email;
$subject = $email_subject_line;
$headers = "From: {$email}" . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To:' . $email . "\r\n" . 'X-
Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

header("Location:thankyoupage.php");
```

**thankyoupage.php (After data has been submitted)**

```
<div class="thankyoucontainer">
    <h1>Thank you, your message has been submitted.</h1>
    <a href="index.php">Go back to home page</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run this code, processor.php is simply just opened. How do I make it so that the code is run? Do I need a certain application installed to run it?

Comment: Keep in mind, what submits the form data results is the <form action="processor.php" method="post" id="myForm"> action being what submits the form data, method which posts the data into the body instead of the URL, and the id is simply optional for custom css styling purposes. if your file for processing the php is named differently, just replace the name of the action with whatever you named your file that has the form processed php code in it.

Comment: To work with any server-side language you need a web-server to run it on. You cannot run it in the browser like JavaScript. If you want to run PHP you should look up how to install Apache to run it. Or better yet, download Wamp (for windows) or Mamp(for mac) it's a web-server packaging kit that comes with the web-servers such as Apache that are necessary to run PHP